# Reference request for a theorem of Schlessinger

Tags: reference-request, deformation-theory

I am reading [The unbearable lightness of deformation theory](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/szendroi/defth.pdf) by Balázs Szendrői.

At page 9 he defines the deformation functor associated to a dgla $\Gamma$ as
$$Def_\Gamma:Art_k\longrightarrow Sets,$$
where $Art_k$ is the category of local artinian rings over $k$ and $Sets$ is the category of sets, sending $R=k\oplus m$ (i.e. $m$ is the maximal ideal of $R$) to
$$MC(\Gamma\otimes m)/(\text{gauges}).$$
Later on we can read:

> **Remark 3.4** By a reasonably standard result of Schlessinger, the functor defined above is pro-represented by a complete local $k$-algebra $R_\Gamma$ in the sense that the functors $Def_\Gamma$ and $\hom_{k-alg}(R_\Gamma,-)$ from $Art_k$ to $Sets$ are isomorphic.

Does anyone have a reference for this result, or at least a precise statement (i.e.: how can one construct $R_\Gamma$?)

Answer (score -1):

See the proof of Theorem 2.11 in http://www.math.harvard.edu/~amathew/schlessingerdef.pdf
you could have easily found this via Google...

Comment: Here is an [update](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1968-130-02/S0002-9947-1968-0217093-3/S0002-9947-1968-0217093-3.pdf) to the link that seems to have died.